# IPHONE: releasing cached data

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Here is a fast one: is there any method for releasing any cached data an application may be using and freeing memory?

I mean data that is cached automatically by the iPhone when you do a Page Curl or other effect in a view, when you load a picture, etc.

The allocations I did I can, obviously release but what about the allocations done by the system itself automatically? Any way to release them?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The system will take care of releasing the objects when it is finished with them, and over-releasing the objects will only cause problems.

For the caches that the system keeps (such as the tabs in Safari), the system will release those automatically when it sends your application the low memory warnings.

There’s nothing you can do about the objects that you don’t allocate yourself.